# Missing annotations after bundle install in OSGi

Tags: java, annotations, osgi, bundle

I am sending a bundle-jar file and install it in my osgi on-the-fly. Works like a charm so far. But as soon as I am checking out the contents my code fails in discovering the annotations that are in the bundle. The annotations are both the same (both bundles, the discovering and the sending one) use the same annotations-jar so they should be the same.
The bundle that is installed is saved to the filesystem after it is received.
Furthermore I was wondering if it might be a problem of different classloaders in osgi. Anybody an idea why the annotations are null in this case?

```
BundleContext context = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(this.getClass()).getBundleContext();
Bundle bundle = context.installBundle("foobar.jar");
bundle.start();

BundleContext context = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(this.getClass()).getBundleContext();
Bundle bundle = context.installBundle("foobar.jar");
bundle.start();
BundleWiring wiring = bundle.adapt(BundleWiring.class);
Collection<String> classes = wiring.listResources("/", "*.class",BundleWiring.LISTRESOURCES_RECURSE);

LinkedList<String> c = new LinkedList<String>();

for (String str : classes) {
    str = str.replaceAll(".class", "");
    c.add(str.replaceAll("/", "."));
}
String classname = c.get(0);

Class<?> clazz = bundle.loadClass(classname);

for (Method m: clazz.getDeclaredMethods()) {
    System.out.println(m.getName());
    TestAnnotation testAnnotation= m.getAnnotation(TestAnnotation.class);
    if (txAnnotation != null) 
        System.out.println("\tsource=" + testAnnotation.sourceUnit() + "; target=" + testAnnotation.targetUnit());
}
```

The annotation looks like this:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface TestAnnotation{
    String a();
    String b();
}
```

Example for annotated class:

```
public class annoClass{

    @TestAnnotation(sourceUnit="a", targetUnit="b")
    public int foo(int i) {
        return 2;
    }

    @TestAnnotation(sourceUnit="xyz", targetUnit="abc")
    public int bar(int i) {
        return 3;
    }

}
```

Manifest of the Receiver:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Receiver
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.foo.bar.receiver.impl
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Bundle-Activator: comfoo.bar.impl.receiver
Import-Package: com.foo.bar.receiver;version="1.0.0",
 com.foo.bar.annotation,
 javax.jms,
 org.apache.activemq.command;version="5.8.0",
 org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0",
 org.osgi.util.tracker;version="1.5.1"
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.osgi
```

Manifest of the Annotations:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Annotations
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.foo.bar.annotations
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Import-Package: javax.jms,
 org.apache.activemq.command;version="5.8.0",
 org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0",
 org.osgi.util.tracker;version="1.5.1"
Export-Package: com.foo.bar.annotation
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.osgi
```

Manifest of the Producer:
(The producer doesn't need the import of annotations, since it's just forwarding)

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Producer
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.foo.bar.producerplugin
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Bundle-Activator: com.foo.bar.producerplugin.ProducerPlugin
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0",
 org.apache.activemq;version="0.0.0",
 org.apache.activemq.command;version="0.0.0",
 javax.jms;version="0.0.0",
 com.foo.bar.brokerplugin;version="1.0.0"
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.osgi
```

Comment: You haven't posted your bundle manifest. Are you sure that `TestAnnotation`'s package is listed as an OSGi dependency?

Comment: Ah, that could be it. Will check this through and will get back at you. thanks for the hint.

Comment: Alright, I restructured the bundles and centralized the annotations as much as possible. Still (even though the imports in the manifests are now all pointing at the same bundle with annotations) txAnnotation = null... how come? :)

Comment: Can't say just based on this. Post your manifests and the FQCNs of the classes involved?

Comment: Which classes are annotated, and which classes are trying to read the annotations?

Comment: Producer sends a bundle that includes annotated classes which is installed to the OSGi environment by the receiver and the annotations examined by it afterwards. The methods of the received bundle can be discovered already. But somehow I cannot access the annotations of these methods.

Comment: Add the annotations to the producer's import. I suspect that it's a classloader issue where the annotation class the receiver is looking for isn't the same class (different classloader) the producer's annotated with.

Comment: The producer has no the annotations imported. shouldn't be the problem though since it is sending a packed jar. so i guess it is not necessary to know anything about it (like i.e. the annotations).
However still not working. the annotations are available in an extra bundle in the osgi and importet whereever needed..
this is weird. :D I am missing something here but can't see what.

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume your annotations are in a different bundle. So you will need to import the packages where the annotations reside in the bundle using the annotations. Additionally you will have to install the bundle with the annotations so the imports can be satisfied.

The easiest way to do this is to use bnd or the felix bundle plugin in your build. It will automatically detect used packages and create your manifest.

In some cases you can also have the problem that you have two bundles exporting the same annotations. For example in the case of jaxb annotations and cxf. As JAXB is part of the jdk the system bundle (OSGi framework) exports them. CXF replaces these with an updated version. So it may happen that your bundle uses the one from the system bundle while cxf uses the updated ones. So they are not compatible. In that case you need to redefine the exports of the system package to remove these packages. This is done for example in [apache karaf](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/karaf/trunk/assemblies/features/framework/src/main/filtered-resources/resources/etc/config.properties).

So in general annotation packages have to be imported like normal classes. The difficult thing is that they are kind of optional for java. So if the annotations are not available then your code will not fail and they will simply be ignored.